# Why this code don't run inside $(document).ready() block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple goal at the page startup, considering that I have a single form and its id is 'formCadastro':

1. Put focus on a button which id is 'btnNovo'
2. Disable the tab index of all components that are at readOnly state inside the form
3. Disable the tab index of all tables inside the form

So I wrote this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        alert("ok");
        $("#btnNovo").focus();
        $("#formCadastro").find('input, textarea, select').filter(":readonly").each(function {
            $(this).attr('tabindex', -1);
        });
        $("#formCadastro").find('table').each(function { 
            $(this).attr('tabindex', -1);
        });
});
```

But it is not even the alert is shown, actually I've tested somethings and found out that the problem is at step two and three, when I try disable the tab indexes of some elements, at those two statements:

```
$("#formCadastro").find('input, textarea, select').filter(":readonly").each(function {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', -1);
});
$("#formCadastro").find('table').each(function { 
    $(this).attr('tabindex', -1);
});
```

What I want to know is how to make this work as expected

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle??

Comment: What does your `console` say

Comment: thanks for the coperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a syntax problem and you need to change:

```
.each(function {
```

for

```
.each(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks, I mistyped that